# QtWebKit how to handle login prompt

Tags: c++, qt, webkit, qtwebkit

Please tell me how to handle web page auth prompt in QtWebKit (maybe some event with possibility to set user name and password) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QtWebkit provides interfaces to operate the web page elements, with the help of these interfaces you can fill the user name and password, and submit the data.

Comment: I'm talking about handling of auth window (like windows credentials window) not just form auth

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. You may replace the QtWebkit's default NetworkAccessManager, then process the authenticationRequired signal. More detailed information in official Browser Demo source code.